# Iterating through a Tuple - Network Flows

Tags: python, tuples, max-flow, network-flow

Hoping for some help, trying to define a function that determines when a team is eliminated through creating a network flow, I am pretty certain I am almost there however there seems to be an error somewhere that I am missing & cannot work out what it is?
Any help is appreciated!!!

**The Initial Question:**

Complete the `team_eliminated` function below that takes a team name stored in `team`, and the `wins`, `games_to_play` dictionaries (which are outputs of the `compute_numbers` function above) and checks whether that team is eliminated or not. Your function should return the Boolean `True` if the team is eliminated and `False` if otherwise.

**This is the  defining function**

def team_eliminated(team, wins, games_to_play):

```
## Compute the best possible win total for the given team
W = wins[team] + sum([games_to_play[p] for p in games_to_play if p[0] == team or p[1] == team])

## Construct sets which don't contain the team
teamlist = [t for t in wins if t != team]
pairs = [p for p in games_to_play if p[0] != team and p[1] != team]

## Construct the index sets for the x variables
idx = [(h, a, h) for h, a in pairs] + [(h, a, a) for h, a in pairs]

## Boolean variable that you need to modify
team_eliminated = None

nodes = ['s', 't'] + [i for i in pairs] + [j for j in teamlist]

arcs = ({((k[0], k[1]), k[2]) for k in idx})

arcs.update({('s', i): games_to_play[i] for i in games_to_play})

arcs.update({(j, 't'): wins[j] for j in wins})

arcs.update({('t','s'): GRB.INFINITY})

outgoing = {i:[j for j in nodes if (((k[0],k[1]), k[2]) for k in idx) in arcs] for i in nodes}
incoming = {i:[j for j in nodes if ((k[2], (k[0],k[1])) for k in idx) in arcs] for i in nodes}

mod = gp.Model('team-eliminated')

x = mod.addVars(arcs, lb=0, ub=arcs, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='x')

for i in nodes : 
    mod.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for j in outgoing[i]) - gp.quicksum(x[j,i] for j in incoming[i]) == 0)

mod.setObjective(x['t', 's'], sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)

mod.update()
mod.optimize()

return team_eliminated
```

**This is the function to implement the above**

def which_teams_remaining(wins, games_to_play):

```
remaining = []
eliminated = []
for t in wins:
    elim = team_eliminated(t, wins, games_to_play)
    if (elim):
        eliminated.append(t)
    else:
        remaining.append(t)
return remaining, eliminated
```

**The Error:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78rop.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting an error in all of this, no  changes except indents:

```
def team_eliminated(team, wins, games_to_play):

    ## Compute the best possible win total for the given team
    W = wins[team] + sum([games_to_play[p] for p in games_to_play if p[0] == team or p[1] == team])

    ## Construct sets which don't contain the team
    teamlist = [t for t in wins if t != team]
    pairs = [p for p in games_to_play if p[0] != team and p[1] != team]

    ## Construct the index sets for the x variables
    idx = [(h, a, h) for h, a in pairs] + [(h, a, a) for h, a in pairs]

    ## Boolean variable that you need to modify
    team_eliminated = None

    nodes = ['s', 't'] + [i for i in pairs] + [j for j in teamlist]

    arcs = ({((k[0], k[1]), k[2]) for k in idx})

    arcs.update({('s', i): games_to_play[i] for i in games_to_play})

    arcs.update({(j, 't'): wins[j] for j in wins})

    arcs.update({('t','s'): GRB.INFINITY})

    outgoing = {i:[j for j in nodes if (((k[0],k[1]), k[2]) for k in idx) in arcs] for i in nodes}
    incoming = {i:[j for j in nodes if ((k[2], (k[0],k[1])) for k in idx) in arcs] for i in nodes}

    mod = gp.Model('team-eliminated')

    x = mod.addVars(arcs, lb=0, ub=arcs, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='x')

    for i in nodes : 
        mod.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for j in outgoing[i]) - gp.quicksum(x[j,i] for j in incoming[i]) == 0)

    mod.setObjective(x['t', 's'], sense=GRB.MINIMIZE)

    mod.update()
    mod.optimize()

    return team_eliminated, wins


def which_teams_remaining(wins, games_to_play):
   
    remaining = []
    eliminated = []
    for t in wins:
        elim = team_eliminated(t, wins, games_to_play)
        if (elim):
            eliminated.append(t)
        else:
            remaining.append(t)
    return remaining, eliminated
```

Comment: I only get an error when trying to implement it using the second set of code.

Comment: I don't have your data, but if I call the function with this: which_teams_remaining("", 25) I don't get any errors in all of your code.  You might want to search Assertion Errors here in stack overflow or in google.  The error seems to imply that your input is causing the problem.

Comment: You might try, 'for t in wins:  elim = team_eliminated(), that is, without the arguments.